# Can I create WSP that deploys a file to 80 directory?

Tags: wspbuilder, solution-package, feature, deployment

I have an existing WSP project with some features in it.
I need to deploy a file to SharePoint `80` folder. Is this possible?

I tried just putting it in project's `80` but WSPBuilder, which I use for creating package, doesn't include it at all.

If it is possible, do I need to create a feature for that? How do I instruct it to put my file in `80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. One way to do this is using FeatureActivatedEvent to copy files from 12 hive to virtual directory and then delete it from 12 hive. 
Check this out:http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/05/06/deploy-files-to-sharepoint-web-application-virtual-directories-at-feature.aspx